# Javascript: selecting all elements that have a specific font-size or font-weight

Tags: javascript, css

in JavaScript, is there a way to select all elements that have a specific style, like a font size or font weight or color without using class or ID?

Comment: Genuine question: Why?

Answer (score 0):

You could select **all** elements (`querySelector("*")`) then loop over the results testing the [computedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Far from efficient, but the only way I can think of.